# Default encryption for CloudPagesURL()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, security, cloudpage, encryption

My client would like to know which encryption does CloudPagesURL() use to encrypt the parameters transferred to the Cloud pages. I am talking about the encryption used to transfer parameters to a Cloud page.

Is there any documentation from SF that I can provide on this? I tried researching this but couldn't find a clear answer.

Thanks,
​​​​​​​Ivan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, it may be useful for someone in the future. Just got an answer from SF Support and it is looking like this:

> "The Marketing Cloud use 3DES, but please note we use it only for
> obfuscation purposes, not for encryption. The information the
> Marketing Cloud obfuscates is not private, and the Query String
> parameter is simply a method to bundle several parameters together
> that the page uses."